# AR With Core Location IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, location, augmented-reality

We have an app where we drop some pins on a map.

So it loads to ar perfectly but it always shows on the screen even though I am way away from that pin location. That pin does not stay at a specific point.

Do you have any idea how to place a pin at a specific location and does not show away from that location

```
var location = CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.610497, longitude: 77.360733), altitude: 0) // ISKPRO
        let image = UIImage(named: "LocationPin")!
        var annotationNode = LocationAnnotationNode(location: location, image: image)
        annotationNode.annotationNode.name = "ISKPRO"
        sceneLocationView.addLocationNodeWithConfirmedLocation(locationNode: annotationNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  VStack {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $manager.Region,interactionModes: .all,showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $trackMode,annotationItems: manager.CampingArray){ area in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: area.lat, longitude: area.lon) ) {
                    Button {
                        manager.selectedArea = area
                        showDetail.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        CampMarker(CampAreaName: area.name)
                    }

                }
            }.onAppear(){
                manager.fit()
                manager.checkManager()
                
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```

This is part of my code;
as you can see I give the camping pins with "annotationItems"
also you can watch [this video](https://youtu.be/hWMkimzIQoU) this video will help you.

Comment: this is on map i am doing this in AR Screen augmented reality with core location